# deploying f-droid server

Tags: python, deployment, webserver, fdroid

I am trying to deploy a simple binary repo in f-droid server as per the instructions in the [manual](http://f-droid.org/manual/fdroid.html#System-Requirements).

Being a complete newbie to python, I couldn't figure out the process. Here is what I have done so far:

- Installed Ubuntu via VirtualBox in my Mac.
- downloaded android SDK and kept it in ~/tools/android-sdk. same goes with NDK.
- cloned fdroidserver and fdroiddata repos and added the path of fdroidserver to $PATH.
- copied fdroiddata to /var/www/ (not sure whether this is right)
- Edited config.py to reflect SDK n NDK path, set repo URL as localhost/fdroiddata
- created repo dir inside fdroiddata, copied an APK in it and tried running fdroid update.py (which throws errors)

I couldnt get the server running. My another doubt: Will it be possible to view some data in server via localhost or the server respond properly only to the request raised from the fdroid android client?

Could someone please guide me in right directions?

- Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out finally with the help of moderators on [f-droid official forum](http://f-droid.org/forums/topic/deploying-f-droid-server-how-to/) :-)

Only fdroidserver tools are needed to generate the repo files and the command to update repo is `fdroid update` and not `fdroid update.py`. They fixed it in the manual now.

Wrote a [tutorial](http://www.gethugames.in/blog/2012/08/fdroid-binary-repo.html) in my blog on setting up a simple binary repo.

Answer (score 1):

We've recently revamped the [F-Droid docs](https://f-droid.org/docs) so things should be easier to find and follow.  The instructions for setting up your own repo are now here: https://f-droid.org/docs/Setup_an_F-Droid_App_Repo